# 2 private sub worksheet_change

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following bit of code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim C As Range, D As Range, v
Set C = Range("C1:C20")
Set D = Range("D1:D20")
v = Target.Value

If Intersect(Union(C, D), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Intersect(Target, D) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = 12 * v
    Else
        Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = v / 12
    End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

Dim H As Range, I As Range, v2
Set H = Range("H8:H11")
Set I = Range("I8:I11")
v2 = Target.Value

If Intersect(Union(H, I), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Intersect(Target, I) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = 12 * v2
    Else
        Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = v2 / 12
    End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

'Sheets("Költségvetés").AutoFilter.ApplyFilter

' first remove filter
ActiveSheet.Range("$F$54:$$67").AutoFilter Field:=2
' then apply it again
ActiveSheet.Range("$F$54:$$67").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>0"

End Sub
```

I wanna have a pie chart that updates whenever a new value is entered, and doesn't show data labels to 0 valued items.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP just asks for free coding.

Comment: If you don't have a line like `If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub` at the top of your code, then you need to be able to handle multi-cell `Target` values, or your code will fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If Intersect(Union(C, D), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

is preventing the second section from running.  Change to

```
Set all your ranges etc

If Not Intersect(Union(C, D), Target) Is Nothing Then 
    '... first section
ElseIf Not Intersect(Union(H, I), Target) Is Nothing Then
    '... second section
End If
```